# Not able to left join two tables using a non numeric column? ora-01722

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, oracle9i, ora-01722

I would like to check, is it possible to left join two tables using a non numeric column?

i.e. where descriptions_cd is a `varchar(10)` and table_cd is a `varchar(10)`:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM descriptions d 
LEFT JOIN tables t ON t.table_cd = d.descriptions_cd;
```

This SQL seems to be giving an `ora-01722` error.  This is in Oracle 9i.

Comment: Are you positive the two columns are both VARCHAR(10)?  Because the error is for a string that won't convert to a `NUMBER` - one of the columns would have to be `NUMBER`.

Comment: Yes, both columns are meant to be non numeric columns.

Comment: Are `descriptions` and `tables` really tables, or are they views which could lead to possible side-effects?

Comment: They are base tables, i can confirm that.

Comment: ANSI JOINS have been freshly introduced in Oracle 9i. Have you tried omitting the `OUTER JOIN` and just write `JOIN` instead? Also, have you tried using the `(+)` notation instead of the ANSI JOIN syntax?

Comment: @Chin Boon, there has to be something missing from your description. Just because they are "meant to be" non numeric columns does not mean they are. Double-check your table definitions.

Comment: Please post the CREATE TABLE statements for `descriptions` and `tables`

Comment: My bet is that you have picked the wrong column from one of your tables to use in the join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, table_cd is not numeric. that explains.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check values of one of these column contain only numeric data (even if the volumn type is varchar) ?